# How do I use a WHERE on a calculated column

Tags: sql

I have a calculated column in my sql query and I want to use it in my where clause, normally I use the table names and then what I want to filter. In this case I don't have that option

this is in my `SELECT` statement, Its a basic margin calculation SELL-COST/SELL*100 to give me the margin.

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(T_CUSTOMERPRICELISTBASESTANDARDRULE_PRICEDEFINITION.C_NETPRICE - T_PRODUCT_PURCHASING.C_LISTPRICEACTUAL)/T_CUSTOMERPRICELISTBASESTANDARDRULE_PRICEDEFINITION.C_NETPRICE ) * 100 Percentage
```

what I would like to do is use the WHERE clause to filter the above statement anything below 15

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT clause, so you can't reference Margin. Wrap your query up in a derived table (or cte).

Comment: What DB server are you using? If that's SQL Server I would look into CTE (common table expressions) to not write the same expression twice.
BTW you can also duplicate the expression in WHERE clause and if it's the same it will be evaluated only once. But it harms readability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a table expression to name that column *officially*. Then the outer query can use it as needed. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select a, b, a + b as c from t
) x
where c > 10 -- "c" exists in the outer query
```

Comment: this work perfectly thank you :) I will accept as soon as I can